# Show that $f$ is bounded in the image of the curve

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I got stuck with the question from homework and have no idea where to start.

let $γ:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^n$ be curve with length and
$f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ such that the line integral of type one is exists **(integral by length)**

We have to show that $f$ is bounded on $Γ = γ([a,b])$ **(The image of the curve $γ$)**

can some one help me with that? I just want a hint where to start from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\gamma$ is continuous, so its image $\gamma([a,b])$ is compact, since $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact. Then, use that continuous functions on compact sets are bounded.

Comment: Is $f$ necessarily a continuous function?

Comment: @AmitBenDavid That depends on the problem. Is $f$ given explicitly, or do you know anything else about $f$ that you haven't stated in this question? If $f$ is not continuous, then of course $f$ isn't necessarily bounded on $\gamma([a,b])$.

Comment: I just know that the line integral is exists. This leads to the function are continuous?

Comment: I don't think one can conclude that $f$ is continuous then. If I remember correctly, line integrals are usually defined for continuous functions only. But just because some integral exists, you can't conclude that the integrand is continuous, take for instance $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then $\int_0^2 f(x)\,dx=1$, but $f$ certainly isn't continuous on $[0,2]$.